# Regex for URL validation which contains hyphen

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this regex for URL validation and it works fine but it doesn't pass if URL contains `hyphen` like `www.i-card.com`, this is a valid domain, it should pass it. Here is my regex:

`^((https?|ftp|smtp):\/\/)?(www.)?[a-z0-9]+(\.[a-z]{2,}){1,3}(#?\/?[a-zA-Z0-9#]+)*\/?(\?[a-zA-Z0-9-_]+=[a-zA-Z0-9-%]+&?)?$`

Comment: Add a `-` to first character class: `[a-z0-9-]+`

Comment: That regex is slightly crazy. It matches many things that aren't URLs and doesn't match many things that are.

Comment: @melpomene can you please give me the example?

Comment: @DheerajAgrawal [Working Example](https://regex101.com/r/WDtZX1/1)

Comment: Doesn't match `http://EXAMPLE.COM` or `http://127.0.44.1/` or `http://cdn.xs4all.nl`. Matches `www"example.com` and `0.aa#1#2#3?-=%`.

Answer (score 3):

Try this version:

```
^((https?|ftp|smtp):\/\/)?(www.)?[a-z0-9\-]+(\.[a-z\-]{2,}){1,3}(#?\/?[a-zA-Z0-9\-#]+)*\/?(\?[a-zA-Z0-9-_\-]+=[a-zA-Z0-9-%\-]+&?)?$
```